# Passing websocket ref to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, websocket

I have established a websocket connection in a Parent component and stored that in a variable `socket` using `useRef`. Now, I am passing this `socket` to a Child component in the props. I want to use this socket in the child component to emit component specific events and update certain state variables specific to the component based on some websocket events.

**Parent Component**:

```js
function Parent(props) {
  const userId = props.userId;
  const socket = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userId) {
      socket.current = services.establishSocketConnect(userId);
    }
    return () => {
      socket.current.close();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Child socket={socket} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  userId:
    (state.userInfo && state.userInfo.user && state.userInfo.user._id) || null,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Parent);
```

**Child Component**:

```js
function Child(props) {
  const { socket } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Child => socket', socket);
    if (socket.current) {
      console.log('attaching socket events');
    }
  }, []);

  return <h1>Child</h1>;
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, otherProps) => {
  return {
    // ...
    ...otherProps,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Child);
```

In the Child Component, `socket.current` is not having the websocket connection. I understand that at the initial render, the value will be null. So, that's what the Child component is receiving initially. So, I tried to add `socket`, `socket.current` to `useEffect` so that Child component would re-render on change of this. But, this is not happening because mutable objects cannot be used as dependencies for `useEffect`, I guess..

Please suggest a way to solve this.

---

Using [Robin Zigmond's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66373075/8208804) with some additional logging.

**Parent**

```js
function Parent(props) {
  const userId = props.userId;
  const socket = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Parent => (initial) socket', socket);

    socket.current = services.establishSocketConnection(userId);

    if (socket.current) {
      socket.current.onopen = onWSOpenEvent();
    }

    let i = setInterval(() => console.log('Parent => (interval) socket', socket), 5000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(i);
    };
  }, [userId]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Child socket={socket.current} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

**Child**

```js
function Child(props) {
  const { socket } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Child => (initial) socket', socket);
    if (socket) {
      console.log('attaching socket events');
    }

    let i = setInterval(() => console.log('Child => (interval) socket', socket), 5000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(i);
    };
  }, [socket]);

  return <h1>Child</h1>;
}
```

This did not work. Here are the logs:

[image: logs]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are passing `socket` as a prop to the child component - which, by design, is a mutable object, whose `current` property gets changed while maintaining the same reference for the entire object. But that doesn't play nicely with React props when you pass the whole object down to the child component - because when that `current` property changes, React doesn't "see" that change (the prop is still the same as it was before - a reference to the same object) so it won't rerender the child.

The solution is very simple - don't pass the mutable object as a prop, but just the `current` property that you care about:

```
<Child socket={socket.current} />
```

Now whenever you reference the `socket` prop in the Child component, it should have the actual websocket connection.

Edit: if you want the current socket value logged in the child component, every time it changes, then the `useEffect`  in the child should be

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Child => socket', socket);
    if (socket) {
      console.log('attaching socket events');
    }
}, [socket]);
```

Comment: The problem is not in the **Parent** component. In the first mount of **Parent**, `userId` is a valid string. So, websocket is being established in **Parent** properly. The actual problem is in the **Child** component where I am not receiving the socket connection in `socket.current` variable.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I didn't realise that - particularly as you talked about trying to add `socket` as a dependency to `useEffect`. I now see the real problem (it's because you are mutating the props you pass to the child component, via the ref). I will edit with (what I now think is) the correct solution!

Comment: I have tried this but It did not work. Still receiving null as `socket` in **Child** component. I have tried `useEffect` in **Child** which dependency as `socket` but even that didn't help.

Comment: Thanks, I'd overlooked that the child was also incorrect. I've added what change is needed there - it sounds like you've already tried this, but it can't hurt being explicit. If this doesn't work then I can't help any more without knowing what exactly gets logged, and how many times.

Comment: I have tried out your solution which I have updated in the question. Receiving `socket` as null in **Child**. Please check

Comment: Can you also try changing the dependency array of the `useEffect` in the parent component to `[userId]` (as I suggested in my first answer)?

Comment: Added that, the issue still exists

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i do when passing websocket ref from parent to child component.

Parent Component:

```js
import React, {useRef, useEffect} from "react";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const Parent = () => {
  const socketClientRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const client = io(SOCKET_URL);
    
    client.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("Connected");
    });

    client.on("disconnected", () => {
      console.log("Disconnected");
    });
    
    return () => {
      client.removeAllListeners();
    };
  }, []);
  
  return (
  <>
    <ChildComponent client={socketClientRef.current} />
  </>
 );
  
}

export default Parent;
```

Child Component:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const Child = ({client}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof client !== "undefined") {
      if (client.connected === true) {
        client.on("connect", () => {
          console.log("Connect From Child Component");
        });
      }
    }
  }, [client]);

}
```